# How can I order these pages in this navigation bar on this old wordpress theme?

Tags: menus, pages, navigation, order

It's using a superceded theme with no support. 
Even so, the theme has been working great for about a decade...

Here is the site: https://www.vertebr.ae

There is no menu to organise in the appearance settings.
This theme orders them alphabetically using this code (I think)

```
    function greenday_get_menu_from_pages() {

    $pages = & get_pages($args);
    if ( $pages ) {

        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            $output = '<li><a href="' . get_page_link($page->ID) . '">' . $page->post_title . '</a></li>';
            echo $output;
        }
    }

}
```

&

```
<?php    greenday_get_menu_from_pages();    ?>
```

I have specified the page ordering with numbers in the page attributes; there is no effect.
I have tried several "page ordering" plugins but they all fail to do the job.

I vaguely remember I was using html spaces to organise the pages ages back, that's not a great workaround anymore as there are too many items in the navigation menu.

```
&nbsp;
```

The pages appear in the correct order in the wordpress admin...

This is my preferred order:

- About Design Products Reviews Gallery Philosophy FAQ News Contact

I am not a programmer so it is beyond my capabilities to code from scratch although I can copy/paste/edit if someone has a workaround... :-/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change code of your `greenday_get_menu_from_pages()` function a little bit, just so that the results are not ordered by `post_title` which is default for [get_pages()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages), but ordered by `menu_order`, which is what most "page ordering" plugins you have tested actually work with.

So here is one new line in your function:

```
function greenday_get_menu_from_pages() {

    $args = array('sort_column' => 'menu_order');

    $pages = get_pages($args);
    if ( $pages ) {

        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            $output = '<li><a href="' . get_page_link($page->ID) . '">' . $page->post_title . '</a></li>';
            echo $output;
        }
    }

}
```

And then, you can install plugin such as [Intuitive Custom Post Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/intuitive-custom-post-order/), go to **Settings > Intuitive CPO** - set it up to be available for Pages as you can see on this screen:

[image: Intuitive Custom Post Order Settings]

And then, go to your **Pages** tab and simply drag and drop the entries there.

Side note: *i've also removed the ampersand & for reference before your get_pages() call, not sure if that was any important, seemed rather obsolete to me.*